# Which systems use character development mechanics similar to The Dark Eye?

Tags: game-recommendation, character-creation, the-dark-eye

I have long been only exposed to D&D and therefore it was quite intriguing to see how The Dark Eye (in it's v4) takes dice and levels completely out of character development.

Been wondering whether there's any other large(ish) (Fantasy) RPG system that do things similar to The Dark Eye (de:"Das Schwarze Auge"), I'll try to name a few points:

- No dice at all involved in character development
- Buy-as-you-go improvement of char abilities by spending earned XP.
- No levels, basically. (A character with "10.000XP" that spent all his XP on his social skills is just as crappy in a fight as a char with 0XP.)
- At creation of your character you add Disadvantages (de:"Nachteile") to your character to gain additional points for abilities.

Comment: Sounds like GURPS, Hero System, Savage Worlds… Basically, there are *tonnes* of similar games. Just search for "point-buy RPG" to find fistfuls of them. (As such, this question will probably be closed because, completely innocently, it assumes the range of RPGs in existence is much narrower than it actually is.)

Comment: As this is a [tag:system-recommendation] question, please adhere to both the [FAQ] and the rules for subjective questions as outlined in [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) and on [our Meta](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/a/1071/760).  In particular, all responses should be based on actual experience and contain references and examples whenever possible.

Comment: The answer is "yes, hundreds of games."